# Shutdown Windows after simulation

Tags: r

I want R to shutdown my computer after my (extensive) simulation and saving results, is this possible?

Comment: You should cautiously save the results yourself.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Provides advice that is wise beyond his years.  If you *must* shutdown before manually saving, save a temporary .Rd file somewhere with all your intermediate results.  You'll be awfully annoyed if you get a minor error while converting the internal results to a nice clean dataset which causes it not to save.

Comment: Simulation& Save results and than shutdown, anwsers below is what I wanted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, look at the function `shutdown` in the package [`fun`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fun).

The flags for  system command `shutdown` depends on your operating system, the function simply calls the appropriately flagged command.

```
fun::shutdown

function (wait = 0) 
{
    Sys.sleep(wait)
    ifelse(.Platform$OS.type == "windows", shell("shutdown -s -t 0"), 
        system("shutdown -h now"))
}
```

Answer (score 8):

R can send commands to the system with `?system`, and so whatever is required for Windows can be done with that:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shutdown.mspx?mfr=true

R has a `.Last()` function controlled by `quit()` (or `q()`) with its `runLast` argument, so this is where you would send the shutdown commands via `system`, so that it occurs after quitting R. Saving objects with R is done with `save` or `save.image`, though there is a default to save as well with `quit()`.

Comment: Thank you for this information, i will look into this options, maybe some of them will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Executing

```
system("shutdown -s")
```

will shut your computer down. Just add it at the end of your script