# Is there a way to shut down the computer from inside R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shutdown Windows after simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981270/shutdown-windows-after-simulation)

I was wondering whether there is a way to shut down the PC after some process has ended in R?

```
somefunction()
Sys.shut.down()
```

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try running a system command like this (for windows only):

```
system("shutdown -f -t 1")
```

For Mac/Linux try (permissions might not allow this, though):

```
system("shutdown -h now")
```

Warning: This command will force close all running processes...

Answer (score 6):

There is a function `shutdown` in the package [fun](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fun/index.html) which will use the appropriate system command to do this.