# R code to turn windows computer off after completion of program

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shutdown Windows after simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981270/shutdown-windows-after-simulation)

I have some time consuming programs that I would like to run overnight.
Is there some R code that I could add to the end of a program to close the application and turn the windows computer off automatically after completion?

Comment: Use `system()` with [DOS shutdown](http://www.computerhope.com/shutdown.htm)

Comment: Apologies. Thank you for the excellent link.